# What happens if I can't make a legal move?

Tags: fury-of-dracula

If I am moving as Dracula it is possible for me to get into a position where I have literally no legal moves left.

For example: I could go to the Mediterranean Sea, go to the Tyrrhenian Sea, and then go to Cagliari. From that point, I do not have the cards to go to either Sea anymore, and there is no land location I can go to.

What happens?

Comment: Could you please clarify which edition you are playing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [rules](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Fury%20Of%20Dracula/furyofdracularules.pdf) cover this on page 13 and 25 when covering Dracula's movement rules

**Crossing His Own Trail**

> Dracula may only move to a location if its
>   card is available to him. Thus, he cannot normally
>   move back into a location while its card
>   remains in his Trail or Catacombs. The only
>   exception to this rule is when he uses his
>   Double Back Power card (see “Dracula’s
>   Powers,” page 20). In the unlikely event that
>   Dracula maneuvers himself into a position
>   where he has no legal move, he is punished as
>   though he were caught cheating (see
>   “Cheating,” on page 25) and then takes his
>   turn as normal (assuming he didn’t lose the
>   game).

**Cheating**

> Hopefully, the Dracula player will never cheat
>   on purpose. But if he makes a move and later
>   finds out that he accidentally moved along a
>   rail route or made a similarly illegal move, it’s
>   important to undo the damage and get the
>   game underway again. However, Dracula also
>   needs to suffer a penalty to make up for the
>   Hunters’ lost time. We suggest the following
>   penalty for a Dracula player who catches himself
>   (or is caught) cheating. Although it may
>   seem severe, the hope is that the Dracula player
>   will quickly learn to be more careful in the
>   future.
>
> • Dracula immediately clears his Trail down
>   to one card and reveals his current location.
>   • Additionally, Dracula loses Blood as
>   though he had just suffered a “Killed”
>   result in combat. However, if this would
>   reduce him to 0 Blood, it only reduces
>   him to 1 Blood instead.

Comment: I had completely missed this. I've spent looking through the rulebook for like half an hour, but did not read that part =/ Thanks!